# How to reset the other SuperMicro Server IPMI password?

Tags: ipmi, supermicro, ipmitool

I know the ipmitool can reset the own server's ipmi password. but how can I reset the other server's ipmi password when I in my server?

I mean, I have a IPMI controller which can access the other server's IPMI address. now one of the servers' IPMI password I have forgot, is it possible in the IPMI controller to reset the forgot password's IPMI password?

---

**EDIT-01**

I can not reboot the forgot IPMI password server, because I can not login to the Server's management page and I am not in the DATA room to reboot it manually.

Comment: `I am not in the DATA room to reboot it manually` - If you don't have the remote credentials already, then I expect you are SOL.

Comment: I have the IPMI controller, which can access them, means can `ping` them. but I forget one of them's IPMI password.

Answer (score 1):

Boot up to the system setup screen (aka bios/efi setup)?  At least some systems allow you to manage authentication there.

Past that you may need to be more specific about the motherboard in the 
supermicro system you are running.